# Right Join doesn't work

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT
  Student.id,
  Student.first_name,
  Student.last_name, 
  count(`Attendance`.`id`) as total 
FROM `karate`.`attendances` AS `Attendance` 
RIGHT JOIN `karate`.`students` AS `Student` ON (`Attendance`.`student_id` = `Student`.`id`)
WHERE 1
  AND `Attendance`.`attendance_date` BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-31' 
  AND (Student.active = '1') 
  AND (Student.type = 'student') 
GROUP BY `Student`.`id` 
ORDER BY total ASC
```

I want all the students records with there total number of attendances in the given range of dates but it is showing only two records of those students which have attendances.
but 
if we remove the date check condition it is working fine.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `attendance_date` for the rows, that were right-joined has a value of NULL. You need to include this case in your condition:

```
WHERE 1
  AND (`Attendance`.`attendance_date` IS NULL
         OR `Attendance`.`attendance_date` BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-31')
  AND (Student.active = '1') 
  AND (Student.type = 'student')
```

Comment: Sorry to say but this is not working, still showing only attended students (:

Comment: SELECT Student.id,Student.first_name,Student.last_name, count(`Attendance`.`id`) as total FROM `karate`.`students` AS `Student` RIGHT JOIN `karate`.`attendances` AS `Attendance` ON (`Attendance`.`student_id` = `Student`.`id`) WHERE 1 AND (`Attendance`.`attendance_date` IS NULL OR `Attendance`.`attendance_date` BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-31') AND (Student.active = '1') AND (Student.type = 'student') GROUP BY `Student`.`id` ORDER BY total ASC

Comment: mhm... your original query was RIGHT JOINING `Students`, and what you posted here is RIGHT JOINING `Attendances`. ^_^

Comment: In Attendance table i have student attendance, i mean i have only those student entries who are attended in the class in  the attendance table.

Comment: Manu, I understand your question. The original query has **different order of joins** then the one you posted in comment above - that's why my solution is not working. Read it closely please.

Comment: Not understand what you are saying?

Comment: In your question: `FROM karate.attendances AS Attendance 
RIGHT JOIN karate.students AS Student` In your modifed query in comment above: `FROM karate.students AS Student RIGHT JOIN karate.attendances AS Attendance`. Order of tables is different.

Comment: Thanks Bro, you are right, query is working fine now, Thanks so much.

Comment: No Manu, it is not. You mark answer as accepted by clicking this empty tick mark somewhere around my answer. The tick then changes to green. :-)